# Trigger Google Maps marker on reload map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map with multiple markers. I can open a info window when i click on the div with the class click-marker.

(Just a snippet ↓)

```
var markers = [];

var counter = 0;    
$.each(d.houses, function() {
    content += '<div class="click-marker" data-id="'+counter+'">';
    content += houseInfo(this);
    content += '</div>';
    counter++;
});
markers.push(marker);

$('body').on('click', '.click-marker', function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[$(this).data('id')], 'click',{});
});
```

But when i reload the map, the on click function doesnt work anymore..
When inserting the function `google.maps.event.trigger` directly in the console it returns undefined. While the Marker object can be found.

How come the trigger won't work after the map reloads?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, I don't see any code to create the marker in the posted snippet.

Comment: Please define "reload"....do you create a new map?